# Trying to download and install with apt-get with specified directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, apt-get

I am trying to do `sudo apt-get --download-only <package_name> ??target_directory??` but i want to specify the download location so that, in future i want to install my pre-downloaded package without internet connection with `sudo apt-get --no-download <package_name> ??target_directory??`. The problem here is, I want to choose the target directories as '/user/desktop/blabla' but don't know how to specify it with apt-get.

If you can help me, I will be grateful :) 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the download directory by using the -o option:

```
apt-get install -d -o=dir::cache=/user/desktop/blabla <package-name>
```